# .NET Application for Controlling System Software

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to design a software in .NET to control every program in Windows. It means after login only they can run their applications or browser.

Give me some idea from where i should start first.

Answer (score 3):

You can't (or at least shouldn't) do this with a managed language like .NET. If you really wanted to do this, you would have to write a hook routine that essentially blocked processes from running unless they were on your approved white list.

But you really shouldn't do this at all through code. Windows already supports locking down a machine in this way using Group Policy. All you have to do is configure the machine as desired (or push out the configuration from a server to an entire network), and you're all set.

Ask more questions about configuring Group Policy over on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).